How to get the token containing page_show_list permission?
I'm creating a facebook tool and the tool requires me to have a token containing the following permissions:
pages_show_list, pages_read_engagement, pages_manage_posts
Can you tell me what kind of token format has those permissions and can you help me how to get that token?
I tried tokens in EAAG, EAAB format but they don't have enough permissions for my purpose so I'm hoping to get another token format that has full permissions (or at least it has the above permissions like I said)

Not sure what "formats" you are talking about there, never heard those terms mentions in relation to Facebook access tokens. You request permissions from the user, via the login flow.
